# login panel issue with user type

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, panel

I have two login pages with username, password and agent as an user type.
1st one is at the front page and 2nd one is inside the site. I have written below function but it is not working for me.

```
function auth_check_user1($login, $password, $agent )
{

     $query= 'SELECT * FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE login = "' . $login . '" AND password ="' . $password . '", AND user_category ="' . $agent . '"  LIMIT 1';
     $r = $db->query ($query);  



  if ($db->numrows($r)==1)
   {
    $f = $db->fetcharray($r);


    if ($f['login'] == $login && $f['password'] == $password && $f['user_category'] == $agent)
     $logged = TRUE;
    else 
     $logged = FALSE;
   }

 else
     {
     $logged = FALSE;
     }
 return $logged;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a syntax error in your query, you used a comma which is not needed

```
     $password . '", AND user_category ="' . $agent . '"  LIMIT 1';
                   ^this comma is not needed
```

You might have problems because of escaping quotes in your query, simply change your quotes as follow

```
 $query= "SELECT * FROM " . USERS_TABLE . " WHERE login = '" . $login . "' AND password = '" . $password . "' AND user_category ='" . $agent . "'  LIMIT 1';
```

Furthermoere I don't understand why you select a row from database using your variables and then check returned data against your variable with an if condition. I think this is not needed and I would remove the if condition since variables are already checked in the query. So your code would look like this

```
if ($db->numrows($r)==1)  {
    $logged = TRUE;
} else  {
    $logged = FALSE;
}
return $logged;
```

Comment: thanks.. but i got new issue now. when i select wrong credentials it gives me an error that username and password is wrong but at the same time it is redirecting to a page which is to be shown after correct login..

Comment: if (auth_check_user1($session->fetch('login'), $session->fetch('password'), $session->fetch('agent')) )
{

   $sql = 'SELECT first_name,id FROM ' . USERS_TABLE . ' WHERE approved = 1 AND login = "' . $session->fetch('login') . '" LIMIT 1';
  $r = $db->query( $sql );

 <?php echo URL; ?>/login_user.php"><?php echo $lang['Menu_User_Login']; ?>
                        <?php echo URL; ?>/index.php?req=logout"><?php echo $lang['Realtor_Logout']; ?>
}

Comment: this is not working for me.. I have added this code on the main page